# Android Studio 3.1.1 not working fine

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, aapt2

Recently I have installed latest android studio 3.1.1 and created new Kotlin demo project but its not working fine. When I open it some aapt2.exe command window open. Please check below screenshot.

[image]

Also when I close android studio its hang and not close. I have to force close it via Task Manager.

I have also try it with java code but nothing is worked.

Comment: upgrade your gradle file to 4.1 and restart android studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Uninstall Android studio ->
2. Delete .android folder ->
3. Clear temp files ->
4. fix registry error using CCleaner or as you prefer ->
5. Restart system ->
6. Reinstall ->
7. Restart system.

That worked and working fine for me now.

**Update :**  Check whether SDK and android studio version are same. In case of mismatch it may not work.

Comment: You missed 5. Sell your old PC; 6. Buy new PC.

Comment: Lol, i thought those checks are only for me .

Comment: USe default sdk location instead of currently downloaded sdk and it works fine. :)

Comment: You didn't mentioned so I may add 8th check in answer about resetting sdk location to default 

Comment: im very bored when get many problem with android studio 3.1, it's not working stable as 2.x